# Layout update GWT

Tags: gwt, layout, rpc

I use RPC calls to connect to mySql and bring text data from there.
My page is defined as split Layout.
my problem is that I don't know how to update the main layout with different text.
if i use the clear() method it will remove all the layout !
"p" is the splitLayout.

RPC:

```
                    rpcService.getChapterTxt(selectedBook,bookChapters[selectedBook], 
                    new AsyncCallback<List<BibleTxt>>(){
                        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) 

                            {
                          Window.alert("Failed getting Chapter");        
                            }

                        public void onSuccess(List<BibleTxt> result) 
                        {
                            int i = 0 ;
                            String verseText ="";


                            //Label verseLabel = new Label();
                            PPanel chapterPar = new PPanel();
                            HTML page= new HTML(verseText);
                            for(i=0;i<result.size();i++)
                                {

                                    verseText = result.get(i).getVerseText();
                                    //verseLabel.setText(verseText);
                                            page.setText(page.getText() + verseText);

                                } 
                            chapterPar.add(page);  
                            //p.clear();

                            p.add(chapterPar); // adds the main layout

                        }

                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't reuse the text component changing its content text instead of continuously detaching/attaching elements to the widget hierarchy. That way should perform better and cause less problems.

Comment: So declare the html object that contains the text outside the onSuccsess() and update it on every call ?

Comment: Exactly that is what I meant

Comment: didn't help... I dont know what to do !! why it needs to be so hard to change the layout content ??!!

Comment: What is difficult? declare a var in java out of the inner function?

Comment: I didn't understand how layouts work... p.add(chapterPar) shouldn't be inside the RPC call, to change the content of the main layout I declared the HTML once as you said and just changed it's content and had the p.add(...) out ! Thanks